# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Can you please tell me what is wrong with this line of code. I am constantly getting unexpected token ILLEGAL error on this line.

```
onClick="fbShare(<?=$results->person_id?>,'<?=addslashes($results->title)?>','<?=$results->person_photo_filename?>','<?=$results->person_name?>','<?=addslashes($results->description2)?>','<?=addslashes($results->description3)?>');"

function fbShare(id, title, image, name, description2, description3){
FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'TEST',
        link: 'http://www.someurl.com/' + id,
        picture: image,
        description: title + ' ' + name + ' ' + description2 + ' ' + description3,
        caption: 'TEST'
    },
    function (response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            // alert('');
        } else {
            //alert('');
        }
    }

)
}
```

Comment: How does the generated HTML looks like in the browser? I assume its a javascript error?

Comment: Use `json_encode` to print the values (don't use addslashes)

Comment: <a href="#" class="social facebook pull-right" onClick="fbShare(948116,'title','image.jpg','name','desc2','desc3');">

Comment: @Barba Is it a javascript error or a PHP error?

Comment: I'm getting this error in console, how can I check if it is JS or PHP?

Comment: Do you get this error when clicking on the button?

Comment: Yes when I click on a button I get that error

Comment: If you get the error on click then it is a problem with JS.

Comment: @Barba With you edit its clear that this error comes from a line inside the fbShare() function. Is there a line number referenced in the error log?

Comment: OK I edited the post, there is complete JS code of a function